# DIv inside my Bootstrap div will not right align (but text does)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align two divs, each of which are inside Bootstrap column divs. I want to align the one in the first column to the right, and the one in the second column to the left. The divs inside are positioned relative, so that content inside them can align absolutely. But even removing that positioning didn't fix my issue. I can't figure it out, because it works on teh plain text i place inside the columns/divs, just as a test, but not on the divs.

**Here is my html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftFeature col-md-6">TESTTEXT<br>
      <div class="blockFeature">
         [types field='square-feature-image' size='full'][/types]
         <div class="blockFeatureOverlay"></div>
         <div class="blockFeatureText">
            <h2>[types field='front-page-feature-tagline'][/types]</h2>
            <h3>[types field='tag-line'][/types]</h3>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightFeature col-md-6">TESTTEXT<br>
      <div class="blockFeature">
         [types field='square-feature-image' size='full'][/types]
         <div class="blockFeatureOverlay"></div>
         <div class="blockFeatureText">
            <h2>[types field='front-page-feature-tagline'][/types]</h2>
            <h3>[types field='tag-line'][/types]</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is my css:**

```
.leftFeature {
  background-color:#F9D069;
  text-align:center!important;
}

.rightFeature {
  background-color:#B6DEFF;
  text-align:center!important;
}

.col-sm-6 {padding:0;}

.blockFeature {
  width:80%;
  background-color:#7F9FA1;
  background-size:100%;
  line-height:0;
  position:relative; /*removing this rule did not fix my issue */
}

.blockFeatureOverlay {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  /*background-color:rgb(158,84,6, 0.25);*/
}

.blockFeature a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

.blockFeature img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.blockFeatureText {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:20px;
  left:20px;
}


.blockFeatureText h2 {
  font-size:2.4em;
  font-weight:700;
  color:#fff;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-bottom:10px!important;
  line-height:100%!important;
  text-align:left;
}

.blockFeatureText h3 {
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-weight:300;
  color:#fff;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-bottom:0!important;
  line-height:100%!important;
  text-align:left;
}
```

**And this is a representation of what i am getting:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU7Av.jpg

**but this is what i want:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtWB8.jpg

It's probably (hopefully) something really obvious. But after 24 hours of messing around, I cannot seem to fix it. I have tried adding text-right or pull-right class on the left hand div, but it either does something different than I need, or doesn't work at all.

thank you for anyone who can maybe help me out?

EDIT: Here are two fiddles i created

1. forked from a fiddle where someone seemed to have already created the bootstrap environment: https://jsfiddle.net/Katrina_B/w4dt8qq7/
2. one with no bootstrap, in case the above is not correct, and someone knows better how to add bootstrap to it: https://jsfiddle.net/Katrina_B/c4kxa06s/

I am completely new to Bootstrap, and rarely use Jfiddle, so apologies if i have done this incorrectly. In any case, in neither example, are the divs doing what i expect or wish them to do.

Comment: <div class="span12" style="text-align: right; float:none ; margin: 0 auto" align= "center"></div>

Comment: @Jenish Where did you get the `span12` class? And the style is used to center the div, but not what the OP wants

Comment: @user2998925 can you post the code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Could you update your code with the output markup instead of the WordPress shortcodes?

Comment: its just example its my class you just have to create yours

Comment: Simply adding `pull-right` to `.blockFeature` under `.leftFeature` seems to [do the trick](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/qc1qm2dq/). Not having the right size, I needed to remove `position:absolute` from `.blockFeatureText`, but you probably don't need to. If this doesn't work, please provide an inspectable example.

Comment: Hi Andrei. Thank you. Your suggestion of adding pull-right to .blockFeatures under .leftFeature did the trick. My problem is now that my .blockFeatures are actually populated into a loop (using a design-builder tool called Toolset). I don't know how to add the class ONLY to the one .blockFeature, and not both. Grrr....     Well, i guess i am on the right track, but very frustrating.  ACTUALLY, it almost works, as you said, it causes a problem with my text and overlay.

Answer (score 1):

simple you should use bootstrap **pull-left** and **pull-right** class to align your divs

```
<div class="leftFeature col-md-6 pull-left">TESTTEXT<br> .... </div>

<div class="rightFeature col-md-6 pull-right">TESTTEXT<br>....</div>
```

Comment: Hi Watson,  Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't affect my layout at all. I want the content (which is a div with class .featureBlock in both cases) INSIDE the bootstrap divs .leftFeature and .rightFeature to align certain ways. Specifically the content in the left div to align right, and the content in the right div to align left.  So, i tried your suggestion but switching teh classes, but that causes the Boostrap divs (.leftFeature and .rightFeature) to switch places, which i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

```
.leftFeature .blockFeature {
   float: right;
 }
```

This style may keep your complete div in right

Comment: Hu Shubhranshu,  that is not working, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Below the div with the class col-md-6 you can use bootstrap again. Try adding a div with `class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2"` for the left side, and on the right side `class="col-md-10"`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftFeature col-md-6">TESTTEXT<br>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2>
        <div class="blockFeature">
          [types field='square-feature-image' size='full'][/types]
          <div class="blockFeatureOverlay"></div>
          <div class="blockFeatureText">
            <h2>[types field='front-page-feature-tagline'][/types]</h2>
            <h3>[types field='tag-line'][/types]</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightFeature col-md-6">TESTTEXT<br>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="blockFeature">
          [types field='square-feature-image' size='full'][/types]
          <div class="blockFeatureOverlay"></div>
          <div class="blockFeatureText">
            <h2>[types field='front-page-feature-tagline'][/types]</h2>
            <h3>[types field='tag-line'][/types]</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Dithanial, Thanks so much for this suggestion. I fixed the missing quotations and tried this, but it doesn't work. It does cause an unexpected shift where the right div goes below the left one, and a lot of other things change too. But it doesn't do as expected.       (Kind of glad, because it seems like an extraordinarily strange way to solve the issue. Is that a guess, or is that typical usage of Bootstrap? I am just now learning Bootstrap and didn't know you could nest columns!?)

Comment: If it's moving one below the other it's because of the built in margins in the bootstrap classes. Try changing your css from col-sm-6 to col-md-6.

Comment: HI Dithaniel. I tried that, but it didn't help. To solve my issue, i had to add the class .pull-right to the .blockFeature INSIDE the .leftFeature div. It's frustrating to me that the text-align:right doesn't apply to a div within a bootstrap column div, but only applies to text. Having to use the "pull-right" class on a div that isn't a bootstrap div seems wrong to me, and unexpected extra work. Maybe it's sense will reveal itself to me once i get more into bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You should use bootsrap predefined **pull-left** and **pull-right** class to positioning div left and right. This could work for you. 
Or you can use css float: left and float: right property.
Example:
.leftFeature {float: left;} and .rightFeature {float: right}

Comment: Hi Pratik, thanks so much for the suggestion. Alas, adding the float classes doesn't have any effect!? And neither do the pull classes. (Although at some point (beforeposting here) I did add a predfined class (I thought it was pull-right) that made the actual .leftFeature div get pulled to the right of the .rightFeature div, which i didn't want. I only want to affect the contents of these divs.